# Efeito hover underline na navegação

Tags: html5, css3, webdesign

Quero fazer aquele efeito hover underline, que ao passar o mouse no elemento, aconteça esse efeito, porém não sei o que estou fazendo de errado

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Coolvetica;
    src: url(templates/AnyConv.com__coolvetica_rg.woff);
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "Coolvetica";
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 720px;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    padding-right: 5%;
    
}

.brand {
    display: flex;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5%;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.brand a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F9DD20;
}
.brand a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F9DD20;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #F9DD20;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F9DD20;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #F9DD20;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

nav ul li a::after{
    display: flex;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F9DD20;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.frase {
    height: 100px;
}

.frase p {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="pt-br">
<!--


-->
  <head>

    <title> </title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-4.6.1-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css.css">

    <style type="text/css">


    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <nav>
          <div class="brand">
              <a href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <ul id="navegacao">
              <li> <a href="">Home</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="">Local</a> </li>
              <li> <a href="">Atendimento</a> </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="principal">
      
      <article>

        <section class="frase">
  
          <p>Slogan</p>


        </section>



      </article>

    </div>


 

    
    <!-- =================================================================================================== -->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- =================================================================================================== -->
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente o seguinte:

```
#navegacao ul li a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Ou se preferir com mais estilização:

```
#navegacao ul li a:hover {
   border-bottom: 2px solid #ff0000;
   transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Neste segundo caso você pode regular o distanciamento da linha com padding, mas aí será necessário configurar o continente do elemento para gerar um efeito mais agradável.